# How do I find substring after using select-string in powershell?

Tags: powershell

How do I continue to get the 12345 as output?

### file.txt

```
MyText: 12345
```

### myscript

```
Get-Content file.txt | Select-String "MyText:" | Select-Object Line
```

Now I would like to save last five characters, how to I retreive them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Select-String cmdlet `-Pattern` parameter expects a *regex* - so you can get your desired output by capturing the five digits. Note that the `Select-String` cmdlet also takes a `-Path` parameter to retrieve the content of a file. This means you can omit the first `Get-Content` command:

```
(Select-String -Path .\file.txt -Pattern 'MyText: (\d{5})').Matches.Groups[1].Value
```